# I want to remove repeated characters in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net.
I need to remove all the repeated characters in textbox

For Example:

```
myy naaaame isss Johnn
```

to

```
my name is John
```

can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Demanding to write code for you is really bad accepted here. Especially if you haven't shown any effort to solve your problem

Comment: If I'd follow the requirements you describe, the output should be `my nae is Joh` to remove **all** repeated characters.

Comment: the output should be...  my name is John

Comment: The **all consecutive** repeated characters should be removed.

Comment: You definitely should read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

So even I, knowing zilch about VB.NET and RegEx figured it out in like 20 mins:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input As String = "myy naaaame isss Johnn"

    ' You need a regex group that matches any char: (.)
    ' ... and a back reference: \1
    ' ... and a count more than one: {1,}
    Dim rgx As New Regex("(.)\1{1,}")

    ' use the regex to Replace by the first char of the match group
    Dim output As String = rgx.Replace(input, New MatchEvaluator(Function(ByVal m)
                                                                     Return m.Value.First
                                                                 End Function))
End Sub
```

Comment: Not your fault but the impossible OP specs, how do you handle a normal sequence of two consecutive characters? IE the word Message becomes Mesage?

Comment: Wel his name is John but he doesn't get the mesage. ;) ... at least not without a dictionary.

Comment: And after this I could it the sack. Goodnight.

Comment: Thank you @Filburt , your answer makes my problem 100% solve.
Thanks stackoverflow a lot.